# Schrodinger's cat and consistent histories

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedingers-cat

I was reading Wikipedia's article on Schrodinger's cat:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat#Many-worlds_interpretation_and_consistent_histories

Quote:
"When opening the box, the observer becomes entangled with the cat, so "observer states" corresponding to the cat's being alive and dead are formed; each observer state is entangled or linked with the cat so that the "observation of the cat's state" and the "cat's state" correspond with each other. Quantum decoherence ensures that the different outcomes have no interaction with each other."

My question is... what concretely it means for different outcomes to interact with each other.

So suppose decoherence was not happening. Then could we have:

1) The cat is observed dead, but the cat is alive (so the observer from one outcome is interacting with the cat from the other outcome).

2) At one point in time "the cat is dead and observed dead", and at a later point in time "the cat is alive, and observed alive" (ie: in reality there's a wave equation which is a superposition of both possibilities... at different points in time we may observe different outcomes but the world is internally consistent at any point in time and the wave equation continues to evolve as it does regardless).

Is decoherence needed to prevent 1), 2) or both?

Thanks.

Comment: Schroedinger's cat died in 1935, when Schroedinger came up with this nonsense. A cat is a living being and living beings can't exist in a perfectly closed box. They die a few minutes after you put them in there for thermodynamic reasons. If Schroedinger had spent even a few minutes thinking about this before he wrote it down, he would have noticed,  that the irreversible radioactive process happens in the interaction between the nucleus and the electromagnetic quantum field, everything after that is classical.

Comment: 1)  If the cat is in state $\alpha$(alive)+$\beta$(dead) then the observer is in state $\alpha$(sees cat alive)+$\beta$(sees cat dead).  You are positing that $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha=0$ simultaneously.  Obviously this can't happen.  2)  Presumably the time evolution of the state (dead) involves at most a phase shift.  Dead cats do not come alive.

Comment: @WillO, so decoherence has no effect here?

Comment: Of course it does... on the first $10^{-18}-10^{-15}m$ where the actual quantum process happens.

Comment: @CuriousOne, so what if decoherence did not happen... what would be the state of things?

Comment: There would still be a dead cat in a box and a really sad memory of Schroedinger, who, after moments of absolute genius completely seems to have lost track of what physics is and does.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Any *theoretically* possible situation that illuminates the basic principles of a theory is worth investigating as a thought-experiment even if it would be impossible to realize in practice (you see plenty of this in general relativity for example). Keeping a large system like a cat in a box isolated from the environment outside the box is impossible in practice but doesn't violate any fundamental principles of QM. And if enough advances in quantum computing happen, it may become possible in the future be able to have complex structured systems temporarily evolving in isolation.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: Schroedinger's cat is not a theoretically possible situation, either, it's simply a misdiagnosis of reality. In case of Schroedinger's cat it has about the quality of bloodletting to cure cancer. Please think about this for a while longer before you try to defend the indefensible.

Comment: @CuriousOne - What theoretical principle do you think makes it impossible? If you can have a system of 2 entangled particles that remains isolated from decohering interactions with any other particles for some significant length of time, likewise with 3 or 4, do you think there is some number N for which this is no longer possible even in theory?

Comment: @Hypnosifl: For starters the fact that living beings can't exist as closed systems. Anybody who thinks that Schroedinger's cat is a useful way to think about quantum mechanics missed the fundamental differences between open and closed systems, without which QM can't be understood at all.

Comment: @CuriousOne - The idea of the Schroedinger's cat thought-experiment is that the *inside of the box* is the isolated system, not the cat alone. There is nothing in either biology or thermodynamics that would prevent an organism from staying alive in a small enclosed system (starting at much lower entropy than the maximum for that system) for a reasonably short time period, say 1 day. As for "open and closed systems" in QM, would you agree the theory allows 2- or 3-particle systems to remain closed/isolated for measurable periods of time? Again, do you think there is any fundamental upper limit?

Comment: @Hypnosifl: Now you made the outcome of the experiment explicitly dependent on the size of the box, which will, eventually get you to where you mentally need to go. Instead of making the box cat size and instead of putting a cat in there, at all (i.e. by dropping all the  irrational magical components that Schroedinger put in there), make the system boundary the size of the nucleus and analyze all cases between fully closed and quantum Zeno. Keep thinking along the lines of what is really important. The cat isn't.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Of course the cat specifically isn't important, it's just an illustration to make the point that the laws of physics themselves don't place any absolute boundary between "micro" systems that need to be treated as being in a superposition of states and "macro" ones that can be assumed to definitely be in one state or another even if we don't know what the state is. Analyzing a system the size of a nucleus would fail to make this point. If you don't think this point is interesting or important that's fine, but some physicists do, and the cat is a fine way to illustrate it.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: The laws of physics do indeed place a boundary between the micro and the macro world. It's the boundary between "closed" and "open" and that's exactly the boundary that Schroedinger didn't explore. That is the boundary that you can explore by varying the size of the box, which will change the spatial, energy and timescale of coherence for the decay of the nucleus in the original experiment. Schroedinger glossed over all of that and he went from genius to irrelevant. That's sad, but if you actually care about physics, rather than physicists, then that's the outcome of this.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Of course there is a boundary between open and closed systems, my point was that there is no boundary on the number of interacting particles that can be present in a closed system, so it's possible in theory to have a macro-sized system which is closed, which would have to be analyzed using the standard quantum rules for closed systems involving a superposition of states. And attacking Schroedinger's genius for not adequately understanding closed vs. open is hindsight bias, *no* physicists came up with the idea of environmental decoherence until H. Dieter Zeh in 1970.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: You can do that, if you like, but you are quickly running into the problem that coherence in macroscopic quantum systems without energy gap is only possible at extremely low temperatures (cryogenic cat?) or ultrashort time (femtosecond cat?) and in quantum systems with energy gap coherence can be resilient (superconducting cat?). Look, Schroedinger was highly confused, he didn't have a multi-particle theory to work with, he didn't have the quantum theory of superconductivity (BCS came in 1957, 22 years later)... so the thing doesn't even match trivial phenomenology of his time.

Comment: @CuriousOne - What do you mean when you say it "doesn't even match trivial phenomenology of his time"? Can you point to *any* physicists of his time who showed awareness that "coherence in macroscopic quantum systems without energy gap" is only possible at ultralow temperatures or very short times? As you said, they certainly wouldn't have been aware of superconductors...

Comment: @Hypnosifl: Superconductivity was discovered in 1911, superfluidity in 1937 (two years after the cat died). Schroedinger made a nonsensical statement that didn't even match the phenomenological physics of his time, he just couldn't have known better, but you can. Actually... he could have known better... had he read Mott's 1929 paper on the emergence of alpha particle tracks from wave mechanics, which basically gave an example calculation of modern decoherence.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Prior to 1957 did physicists understand that superconductivity specifically had to do with quantum coherence though? If not it wouldn't be relevant here. I don't know of Mott's paper, but I'm just asking whether there were any other physicists *at the time* who pointed out that macroscopic superpositions were impossible in practice for any of the reasons you mentioned (pointing to conflicts with phenomenological physics rather than theoretical analyses would be fine), or if this is just a case of "hindsight is 20/20".

Comment: @Hypnosifl: If you are asking the science history question " Was Schroedinger's cat relevant physics in 1935?", then the answer is no, it wasn't. It didn't explain anything of importance (as it's 100% wrong, even that explanation would have been 100% wrong) and the people who really made science history in QM at the time, like Dirac,  had long moved on to relativistic systems (ten years earlier, actually), which provide the self-consistent frameworks for the quantum mechanical "mystery" that Schroedinger and Einstein just couldn't let go of.

Comment: @CuriousOne - That definitely isn't what I was asking (whether or not a hypothetical thought-experiment is 'relevant physics' seems a rather ill-defined question anyway, but certainly plenty of smart professional physicists thought it was worth discussing).  I was asking if the reasons you argue it should have been seen as obviously impossible *at the time* were actually realized by any physicists of that era. If not, that would suggest that it only seems obvious to you because you have the benefit of hindsight.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: The decoherence visible in nuclear reaction product tracks was observed and theoretically correctly explained by Mott in 1929, which means that Schroedinger simply either didn't know or didn't understand the level of knowledge of his time. That plenty of authors didn't do any better since is not an excuse for Schroedinger, it's a reminder for all physicists to _think_ before repeating theoretically and phenomenologically shaky and in this case outright false fairytales. I was given the correct explanation for the cat in my first QM class a long time ago, btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38655/discussion-between-hypnosifl-and-curiousone).

Answer (score -1):

Think about it like this: Say Schrodinger's Cat is in his box in a windowless, soundproof room. An observer enters the room, closes the door, checks on the cat, closes the box back up. If the cat's alive, he stands there. If the cat's dead, he shoots himself. Now, before another observer opened the door, the first observer would be, like the cat, in quantum superposition and alive and dead at the same time until observed.

Comment: Take the cat and everything else out of the equation. Enter a completely isolated room just barely large enough to contain you. How long are you going to be alive?

Comment: Can we get past the cat? It's an intentional absurdity. It can be Schrodinger's LED for all it matters.

Comment: That's what I just said. Take the cat out and analyze the problem correctly. When does decoherence happen? Schroedinger had it all wrong and  so does everybody who believes in the cat being a useful teaching tool for quantum mechanics.